# Flat file down load and saving in DB

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

I want to download a flat file(, delimited) from a server,process it and save it in DB(oracle)... 
What i was thinking was to download the file save it locally in hardisk then read the file line by line,split the file content based on "," using string buffer and connect to the DB execute the insert query when i get one row...

Sample of how flat file look
"1","anna","India","2","beena","USA".....

```
Person
-----------------------------
Numb      |    name     |     country    |
-----------------------------
1         |anna         | India          |
2         |beena        | USA            |
-----------------------------
```

It is taking me around 5 minutes as the input file is large.... Can anyone suggest me better solution??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use [Sql Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ)

Comment: Yes, oracle sql loader will be a better option for this purpose

Comment: Thx for the response!!!!.... but when i tried using it through java didn't return the status and logging the status is required for us to keep the log of the status

Comment: Is it possible for you to do special insert in separate table at the end of data load. In this case you can check for data load status by yourself in java - eg. no records mean import failed.

Comment: Does this: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=511577 seems to be helpful?